# how can I apply a variable delay to a serviceline in anylogic?

Tags: variables, service, delay

I want to apply a variable delay to the ticket gates of a train station. The service line only allows me to put a constant delay. I want the delay to decrease at peak time.

I tried to create a variable fed from the database, but the Anylogic did not accept it. anylogic error said that it can not recognise it in database.

Can you please help me to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The delay is re-calculated every time an agent enters the service of a ped service block, so it's definitely not a constant delay.

The default is in fact a distribution uniform(2.0,3.0); and a distribution is not a constant.

You can also define a function in the delay and in the function you can make any calculation you have ever imagined in your wildest dreams, including using databases. The error you get it's only because you implemented it incorrectly, but since you kept what you did as a high-security secret, we will not be able to help you in explaining why it didn't work when you tried, but it's definitely 100% possible.

Comment: Thank you very much Felipe. You are right there was not enough details. I mentioned in my question that " I created a variable" and imported an array of delay for every 30min that changes at 3.30-5.30pm from 2 seconds to zero seconds.

The problem is in the setting of the variable. "The variable is fed from the data base that replace the uniform(2.0,3.0).  The error is that anylogic say that it cant  recognise it in the data base." I had to choose a condition when setting the variable and I chose 3.30pm.

Comment: you really want to keep what you did exactly as a secret right? ... imported an array of delay, what does that even mean... then i'm sorry but I don't think you will be able to get any help.. you need to learn how to ask questions... read this article: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and advice. I read the article and it was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I am so sorry, but it was not intentional.

I am importing data from an excel file. The excel file contains a sheet that has two columns, a time column [1am,1.30am,............] and a delay column [2,2,2,2,2,0,0,2,2,.....].

I tried to assign database file to a schedule, and assign the schedule to a variable 'gatedelay' but it did not work an it said 'cannot convert schedule integer to int'

I also tried to assign the file directly to the variable 'gatedelay' but it did not work either 'Not unique database value!'.

I hope that this information is clear. I apologise for the confusion, and thank you very much for your help .

Answer (score 0):

I managed to control the delay by creating a counter that counts accumulate the cycles of the event "count++;". In the code below, 59400 is equivalent to 4.30 pm and 64800 is equivalent to 6 pm.

{

```
if(count >=59400 && count < 64800)
{
   gatedelay = 0;
}

else 
{
   gatedelay = 2;
}
```

}